# MYSQL Creating Procedure

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a procedure  in MYSQL which just selects all the rows from a table.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE  getAll_Temps() 
BEGIN  
SELECT * from temp1
END $$
```

But I am getting this error,

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1.

Comment: Try: `... SELECT * from temp1; ...`, remember the semicolon (`;`) at the end of the sentence.

Comment: It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below query.You miss the `;` at the end of the query.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE  getAll_Temps() 
BEGIN  
     SELECT * from temp1;
END $$
```

Hope this helpful to you.